# question in math logic: find the d.n.f. and c.n.f.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

The question is as follows:

> Find the disjunctive and conjunctive normal forms of the following:
>   $$
> (A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \to \neg C) \to (A \to \neg B))
> $$

My solution is as follows, but I can't go far

[image]

Comment: In line 2 you have forgotten the parenthese, thus line 3 is wrong; it must be : $(A→(B→C))→(\lnot (\lnot A \lor \lnot C) \lor (\lnot A \lor \lnot B))$

Comment: Omnomnomnom has shown how the propositional formulas can be done using MathJax/LaTex.  In the process of "translating" your handwritten work to "typeset" mathematics, I think you will find the solution to at least half of this exercise.